# Bool in IQueryable

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, ado.net

I have following errors

```
Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'LightSwitchApplication.PatientsTelephoneFollowupDetail' to 'bool'   
Error   2   Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type 'System.Func<LightSwitchApplication.PatientsTelephoneFollowupDetail,int,bool>' because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type
```

The code is

```
partial void StatusCallBackRequired_PreprocessQuery(ref IQueryable<PatientsTelephoneFollowupDetail> query)
{

   query = query.Where(p=> p.PatientsMasterItem.PatientsTelephoneFollowupDetail.LastOrDefault(c => c.Status == "7" ));

}
```

I would like to return the patients records with last telephone status as 7.

Comment: You need to be a bit more explicit in what you want.  I don't like answering questions that it looks like the OP made no effort to make clear.

Answer (score 3):

`.LastOrDefault` will still return a `PatientsTelephoneFollowupDetail`, which, as the error suggests, is not a true or false value. If you want to check for the item's existence, use [`.Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx):

```
query = query.Where(p => p.PatientsMasterItem.PatientsTelephoneFollowupDetail.Any(c => c.Status == "7"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The delegate inside the `Where` should return a boolean.

```
p => p.PatientsMasterItem.PatientsTelephoneFollowupDetail.LastOrDefault(c => c.Status == "7" )
```

will definitely not be one.

What exactly would you like to do?

Comment: I would like to return the patients records with last telephone status as 7

Comment: You could have added that to your question, that would have helped *tremendously*  (BTW, you can still do that.)

Comment: Just realized I didn't add expected result. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using [`.Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select.aspx) not the [`.Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.where.aspx) clause.